# Can a PHP Session span through sub-domains?

Tags: php, session-variables, subdomain

Is there a way to make a php session span through my www.domain.com as well as sub.domain.com??? just using `session_start()` and `$_SESSION['foo'] = "bar"` does not work...any suggestions? the PHP manual does not say anything about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try setting the cookie domain

ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".domain.com");

this will set all sub domains within the domain.com to be see as the one domain

Answer (score 2):

The default session tracking in PHP relies on cookies (PHPSESSID, by default, if memory serves).

You can set the domain using [session_set_cookie_param()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) (but you must do so before calling session_start(), I think) -- or  you can set it in php.ini, or .htaccess like:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".domain.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question.

[PHP: Cookie domain / subdomain control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348282/php-cookie-domain-subdomain-control)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are other answers, but you could use `session_set_save_handler` to store your sessions in a database. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php