# Multi domain session showing weird behaviour in PHP

Tags: php, session, subdomain

I have edited `session.cookie_domain = ".mysite.in"` in php.ini to share one single session for same user across all the sub domains of my site.

But it is not working weird. Now if I open a session at "www.mysite.in", it gets shared with "mysite.in"(no www), but not with "oth.mysite.in".

PS : The session did not get shared to "mysite.in" before. So edit definitely has some effect.

Comment: Discussion here might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348282/php-cookie-domain-subdomain-control  including use of [session_set_cookie_params()](http://us1.php.net/session_set_cookie_params)

Comment: neither ini_set nor session_set_cookie_params work for me. so I used php.ini. But it is half working.

Comment: Go check the `Set-Cookie` that your browser receives, and check whether or not it shows that same cookie value for `oth.mysite.in` domain.