# How to set php cookie to parent domain and one sub domain?

Tags: php, session, cookies

How to restrict php cookie to parent  domain and one sub domain?

Having 2 subdomains stage.example.com & secure.example.com.

Need to aloow the cookie set on parent domain to secure.example.com alone, but restrict cookie from stage.example.com.

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348282/php-cookie-domain-subdomain-control

Comment: so Cookie::forever('timezone', $timezone, time()+86400*30, '/', '.example.com');    will do the trick for me? (I dont want parent site cookies to enter into stage.example.com)